# Last Updated trigger for multiple tables

Tags: sql-server, triggers

We have a table tbl_siteinfo with two fields: siteid (pk) and lastupdated.

We have several other tables such as tbl_users, tbl_customers, tbl_prices, tbl_hours which contain different types of data, but all of them have siteid as a primary key.

We would like to create trigger(s) that will cause the lastupdated field in tbl_siteinfo (for the correct siteid row) to be automatically updated on any insert/update/delete action on any of the other tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have access to the data in the record updated via the DELETED and INSERTED tables. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx).

So a trigger for the users table could look like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_users_siteinfo ON tbl_users
    FOR UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE tbl_siteinfo SET lastupdated = GETDATE()
    FROM inserted JOIN tbl_siteinfo ON inserted.siteid = tbl_siteinfo.siteid
END
GO
```

Or you could do a WHERE siteid IN (select siteid FROM inserted) instead of joining.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/165c0/1)

Comment: So I would need three triggers for each table?

Comment: @user1480192 - You can specify a list of verbs in the trigger definition, e.g. `FOR DELETE, INSERT, UPDATE'.  It will fire for any of the listed actions.  [Ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx).

Comment: @user1480192: yes, you need to have it on each and every table that needs this functionality. There is no "global" trigger concept, nor can you define a single trigger to be attached to multiple tables

Comment: @user1480192 - A trigger can execute a stored procedure, so you can have multiple triggers defined that execute common code.  In this case the operation is sufficiently trivial that it isn't worth the effort.